# How in Visualforce to add the duplication error to a page

Tags: visualforce, duplicate-management

I had to create a vfp for the "Lead new"-page, because I had to add a few lines of jscript into it.
Now Duplicate Rules won't work properly. When I try to save a dupe I get the Error properly but there is no save(ignore) button.

How it Should Look
[image: How it should look:]
How it looks:

[image: How it looks:]

Answer (score 4):

You can provide the same functionality in apex using [DuplicateRuleHeader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Database_DMLOptions_DuplicateRuleHeader.htm) class

Below is the sample code to get you started

```
Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions(); 
dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.allowSave = true;
dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.runAsCurrentUser = true;
Account duplicateAccount = new Account(Name='dupe');
Database.SaveResult sr = Database.insert(duplicateAccount, dml);
if (sr.isSuccess()) {
    System.debug('Duplicate account has been inserted in Salesforce!');
}
```

Depending on allowSave boolean you can either force save or stop the save action .

Comment: Thank you. That is pretty much what I looked for, sadly I cant use Apex (Working in a Professional Edition). Is there maybe a way to include 2 custom buttons, one to ignore the rule and anotherone to redirect the user to a duplication check?

Answer (score 1):

Please use below syntax to include any custom button into your VF page:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.Your_Object_c.Your_Custom_Button_Name_c)}" value="My custom button"/>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not sure he's actually looking for a custom button. I think he wants the standard save button.