# Add DupeCheck in custom new Lead-VisualForce, without Apex

Tags: visualforce, leads, duplicate-management

I asked this question in a previous [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/112611/visualforce-add-the-duplication-error-to-viusal-force-page?answertab=active#tab-top) but never received an answer I could realize.

I'm working in a PE, so I don't have Apex and can only work with standard controllers.

I had to create a VfP for the "New Lead"-page, reason being the need for a few lines of jscript added, before the creation of the Lead. 
Now Duplicate Rules won't work properly. When I try to save a dupe I get the proper Error but there is no way to ignore or merge it, so I either have to deactivate the message or I'm stuck in the creation.

How it should look:
[image: How it should look]
How it looks:
[image: How it looks]

Comment: i looked at the previous post and the redirect idea came to me as well, you need to redirect to a standard unoverridden New Lead page.  `URLFOR` with the fourth parameter `no override` set to true. See http://salesforcesource.blogspot.com/2008/12/urlfor-function-finally-explained.html