# How to display duplicate contacts on custom lead convert page?

Tags: lead-conversion, duplicate-management, data.com

I have a custom lead convert page.

We have enabled the data.com duplicate rules, and now, when there is a duplicate contact upon conversion, I get an error on the custom page:

> Error:DUPLICATES_DETECTED

While this behaviour is expected, I can not complete the conversion.

1. How can I display the 'Save and ignore error'
2. How can I display the 'found duplicate contacts' so I can either select the contact to use, and/or merge into it?

   - I do not want to remove the 'Alert' notification form the 'Action on Create' step if possible. That's just allowing to create duplicates.

Comment: Are you using a visualforce page & a controller ? [This question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/112611/visualforce-add-the-duplication-error-to-viusal-force-page) has an example of modifying your `DmlOptions` used to do the conversion. I'm not sure this is an answer tho, since you didn't include code or visualforce/apex tags.